# Silverlight Change Foreground of selectedItem on Datagrid

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, datagrid

This issue seems so easy, but it is really difficult to figure out how to do it.

I want to use the `VisualStateManager` to change the font color of the selected row inside my Datagrid. But in the default layout there are no properties with Foreground values. I have tried adding a ContentControl but ran into some issues. I also played around with all the different properties.

I am probably missing something simple, any suggestions?

This is the default template "Unedited".

```
 <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                        <sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid x:Name="Root">
                            <sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="DetailsVisibleTransition">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentHeight" Storyboard.TargetName="DetailsPresenter"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>
                            <sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NormalAlternatingRow">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NormalSelected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOverSelected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnfocusedSelected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFE1E7EC" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="InvalidVisualElement"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FFBADDE9" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="InvalidVisualElement" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FFF7D8DB" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                            <sdk:DataGridRowHeader x:Name="RowHeader" sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                            <sdk:DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="CellsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True"/>
                            <sdk:DataGridDetailsPresenter x:Name="DetailsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="BottomGridLine" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        </sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found a fix. But it is not good for Peformance.

First you Wrap your DataGridCell Presenter inside a ContentControl.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Foreground="Green">
      <sdk:DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="CellsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True"/>
</ContentControl>
```

Then you can add a `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to your visual state and reference your Control name.

```
<VisualState x:Name="NormalSelected">
   <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Yellow"/>
      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```